# discord.js check if message.author has role

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So I have this code and it keeps saying that property 'cache' is undefined. Is there a way to fix this? Here is my code:

```js
const doggorole = message.guild.roles.fetch("role-id");
if (message.author.roles.cache.get(doggorole.id)) {
    // Code Here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`message.author`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=author) returns a [`User`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User), which has no `roles` property. What you are looking for is [`message.member`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=member) which returns a [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember).

---

```js
const doggorole = await message.guild.roles.fetch("role-id");
// Since RoleManager.fetch returns a Promise you should wait for the response.

if (message.member.roles.cache.has(doggorole)) {
    // Code Here
}

// You should use Collection.has() to see if the role is in GuildMemberRoleManager.cache.

// I suggest using the cache instead of manually fetching the role from the API.

// Note that if you do GuildMemberRoleManager.cache.has("ROLE-ID") you don't need to fetch the role at all.
```